# Файл TSV в DataTable

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

У меня есть файлы с данными в формате "tsv" их нужно (спарсить|прочитать|преобразовать) в DataTable для 
последующей обработки этих данных.

Можно ли это сделать, не читая построчно файл, а загрузить сразу? Как ответ из SqliteDataAdapter добавить в DataTable.

Или предложите варианты где ещё можно обработать данные если не в DataTable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1166419/7482894

Comment: Ну так там тот же перебор построчно файла.

Comment: Невнимательно смотрели, там используется `OleDbDataAdapter`

Comment: В этой же теме, что вы дали [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1166414](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1166414)
Хоть и с перебором но на десяток строк меньше чем у меня )